# Gradle Error while publishing c++ cmake-library build to local repo

Tags: c++, maven, gradle, cmake

Trying to publish  the sample [cmake-library](https://github.com/gradle/native-samples/tree/master/cpp/cmake-library) project to local repo. tried both with maven-publish plugin and org.gradle.samples.custom-publication but both failed.

#### Expected Behavior

Was expecting the cmake specific library (list) to publish to local directory repo successfully.

#### Current Behavior

```
Execution failed for task ':list:generateMetadataFileForMainPublication'.
  Invalid publication 'main':
    - Variants 'debugLink' and 'releaseLink' have the same attributes and capabilities. 
   Please make sure either attributes or capabilities are different.
    - Variants 'debugRuntime' and 'releaseRuntime' have the same attributes and 
   capabilities. Please make sure either attributes or capabilities are different.
```

#### Context

The thing i am trying to do is publish our current c++ 3rd party dependencies (which mostly uses cmake) to any gradle compatible repo so that it can be consumed by our main c++ project or any other project for that matter.

#### Steps to Reproduce (for bugs)

Just launch the publish command in [cmake-library](https://github.com/gradle/native-samples/tree/master/cpp/cmake-library) root

`./gradlew publish`

#### Environment

- Build scan URL: https://scans.gradle.com/s/2ot6auxbnq4qy

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in the latest commit of the gradle native samples repo. 
You can see the [reply](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-native/issues/1054). just pull the latest commit!!